# Export Eclipse RCP application to runnable jar file

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-rcp

I have a Eclipse RCP 3 application and need to create a runnable jar from it.
When I use the export feature in the plugin.xml file it creates a single jar file in a plugin folder. Is it possible to generate a executable jar file from the Eclipse RCP 3 application? A jar file that can be run outside of Eclipse EDI.

[image: Eclipse RCP export function]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Eclipse RCP is an executable file plus many plugins and features. Eclipse itself is an Eclipse RCP, all RCPs have the same format as Eclipse.

If you have an xxx.product file for your RCP use the 'Eclipse product export wizard' link on the first page of the product editor. Otherwise use 'File > Export > Plug-in Development > Eclipse product'.

It is not possible to create a single executable jar for an RCP.

Update: The 'File > Export > Plug-in Development > Eclipse product' method of producing a product is now deprecated. The official method now is to use Eclipse Tycho [tycho](/questions/tagged/tycho) and Maven [maven](/questions/tagged/maven).